# How to check after popping a ViewController, the ViewController on top of the stack, is a particular one?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Suppose I am currently on `BaseViewController` . I can approach this view controller class from 2 other view controllers, say A and B. So when I pop `BaseViewController` how do I check if A or B is present on top of the stack? Here is my code below(inside `BaseViewController`):

```swift
func goToAOrBViewController {
   // If after popping viewController is A do this
   navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
   // If after popping viewController is B do this
   // Instantiate B and push it
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `BaseViewController` class:

```swift
func goToAOrBViewController() {
   guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else { return }
   navigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
   guard let viewController = navigationController.topViewController else { return }
   if viewController is ViewControllerA {
      // Do something for A
   } else if viewController is ViewControllerB {
      // Do Something for B
   }
   // You need not put else-if case if you are sure BaseVC is reachable from A and B only (just use else)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to do this

First and easiest method

```swift
    func visibleViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
        if let window = appDelegate!.window {
            return window?.visibleViewController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func goToAOrBViewController {
       // If after popping viewController is A do this
       navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
       if visibleViewController() == viewControllerA{
           //Do stuff for A
       }else{
           //Do stuff for B
       }
    }
```

Second and obvious method

```swift
    let topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    if topController == viewControllerA {
        //Do stuff for A
    }else{
        //Do stuff for B
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pop and push view controller at the same time.

not tested:

```
navigationController?.viewControllers.removeLast()
let topVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.last

if topVC == A {
  navigationController?.viewControllers.append(A)
  navigationController?.setViewControllers(A, animated: false)
} else {
  navigationController?.viewControllers.append(B)
  navigationController?.setViewControllers(B, animated: false)
}
```